# Spring configuration for hibernate interceptors circular dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to implement an hibernate interception to create a log table in my spring based project and I am struggling on the configuration file.
Everything is working perfectly fine however the interceptor never trigers.

Im my Interceptor I have `@Autowired` my Dao because I need to acces it to save a new input in the LogTable. All Daos have the session factory in parameter so when I try to add

```
<property name="entityInterceptor">
    <bean class="com.mypackage.MyLoggingInterceptor"></bean>
</property>
```

to the **sessionFactory** bean I have a circular dependency :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [URL]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'MyLoggingInterceptor' while setting bean property 'entityInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyLoggingInterceptor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.mypackage.UserLogDao com.mypackage.MyLoggingInterceptor.userLogDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserLogDao' defined in URL [URL]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
```

And If I don't add the `entityInterceptor` property my programm works fine but the interceptor is never called. What should I do to resolve this circular dependancy ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement circular dependency by annotating the `@Autowired` property with `@Lazy`.